# Calculate Age JavaScript

Tags: javascript, utc

How is this age function calculated?

Specifically where does the "7656656e5" value used come from?

I'm looking to calculate age for someone born 03/31/1994

```
    Age = function() {
    var e, o;
    return renderAgeLoop = function() {
      setInterval(renderAge, 100)
    }, renderAge = function() {
      var n = 7656656e5, //Where does this value come from?
        r = new Date,
        t = r - n,
        a = t / 315569e5;
      e = $("#major"), o = $("#minor");
      var i = a.toFixed(9).toString().split(".");

      var d = new Date();
      console.log(d.toUTCString())

      e.text(i[0]), o.text(i[1])
    }, {
      renderAgeLoop: renderAgeLoop
    }
  }
```

Comment: what 8066656e5 value are you talking about?

Comment: @thanksd Sorry! Meant to say "7656656e5"

Comment: where did you get this script from

Comment: In any case this function does some wonky stuff, if all you want is to calculate someone's age. You should rewrite it, or find some other example.

Comment: That looks to be the epoc value of the dob.... but in this case since [exponent notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) is used the dob is `Apr 06 1994`

Comment: For `03/31/1994` it should be `765072e+6`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line here

```
var n = 7656656e5
```

Is a method of expressing numbers in JavaScript. I believe it refers to scientific notation.

It takes the number `7656656` and multiplies that by `10 ^ 5`, which is the `e5`.

If you run it in your console (Chrome Developer Tools) you will see something like this

```
=> 765665600000
```

As for what that number represents, I noticed you are comparing that value with `new Date()`. So it probably represents the number of miliseconds since the January 1st, 1970 epoch.

Anyways, if you are looking to calculate age, here's a better approach.

```
var startTime = new Date("1990").getTime()
var currentTime = new Date().getTime()

var age = currentTime - startTime/Math.floor(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
```

Best possible solution though is checking out the excellent library `MomentJS`. It's much easier to work with.

http://momentjs.com/

Comment: So is that "765665600000" value = milliseconds since 01/01/1970?

Comment: You are comparing with a date. That would be my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
Age = function() {
    var e, o;
    return renderAgeLoop = function() {
      setInterval(renderAge, 100)
    }, renderAge = function() {
      var n = 762498000000, //milliseconds between Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 and Mar 31 1994 00:00:00
        r = new Date,
        t = r - n,
        a = t / 31556900000; //milliseconds in a year
      e = $("#major"), o = $("#minor");
      var i = a.toFixed(9).toString().split(".");

      var d = new Date();
      console.log(d.toUTCString())

      e.text(i[0]), o.text(i[1])
    }, {
      renderAgeLoop: renderAgeLoop
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript function to get age by passing birth date:

```
function getAge(birthDate) {
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(birthDate) !== "[object Date]") return
    return Math.floor((new Date() - birthDate)/31557600000);
}

// Example:
console.log(getAge(new Date("1993-01-22T00:00:00.000Z")))

// Output:
// 28
```